# How to read uploaded file data without saving it in Flask?

Tags: python, file, flask

First uploading a file using html form. I don't want to store that file in the project directory. Without saving how can I read all the file contents?

Comment: why would you need to save anything if what you want to do is read?

Comment: this problem was many times - you can use `io.BytesIO()` to create file-like object in memory and write in this object. Later you can move to the beginning of file using `.seek(0)` and read it like normal file or send it.

Comment: what do you want to do with this file? Some functions may read directly from uploaded file without writing on disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only to read data from file then simply use `.read()`

```
uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

data = uploaded_file.read()

print(data)
```

---

And if you want to use it with function which needs filename then usually it may work also with `file-like` object and you can use it directly

ie. `Pillo.Image`

```
from PIL import Image

uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

img = Image.open(uploaded_file)
img.save('new_name.jpg')
```

ie. `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
```

---

You can also use `io.BytesIO()` to create `file-like` object in memory.

```
from PIL import Image
import io

uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

data = uploaded_file.read()

file_object = io.BytesIO(data)
#file_object.seek(0)

img = Image.open(file_object)
img.save('new_name.jpg')
```

```
import pandas as pd
import io

uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

data = uploaded_file.read()

file_object = io.BytesIO(data)
#file_object.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(file_object)
```

But this is more useful when you want to save/generate data without writing on disk and later send it back to browser.

```
uploaded_file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')

img = Image.open(uploaded_file)

# generate smaller version
img.thumbnail((200,200))

# write in file-like object as JPG
file_object = io.BytesIO()
img.save(file_object, 'JPEG')

# get data from file
data = file_object.getvalue()  # get data directly
# OR
#file_object.seek(0)           # move to the beginning of file after previous writing/reading
#data = file_object.read()     # read like from normal file

# send to browser as HTML
data = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
html = f'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, {data}">'
```